# Allow more frequent rep re-calculations

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

> Reputation cannot be recalculated more than once per day.

I am positive it was more than a day ago.  Hard to argue with a machine though.  Anyway, it is a good workaround for an obviously wrong rep total for a day.

[image]

It is painful to use though, the feature is blocked by a 24 hour interval, it doesn't go by day as the message says.  In other words, it doesn't reset at 0:00 UTC, you have to wait for 24 hours or more before it can be used again.

Which requires an alarm clock.  Please allow recalcs in, say, a 23 hour interval.

Comment: The server clock resets at 0GMT, so you could recalculate it at 8:01pm EDT, and then not be able to recalculate it until 8:01pm EDT the following day.

Comment: @Richard Is it 24 hours from the previous recalc?  I thought it was once per server day - ie, a flag is set in the DB, and all the flags are cleared at 0GMT.

Comment: @Adam It's once per 24 hours. I don't need to recalc often, but every time I do they tend to come in two at a time, haha, so I've actually been blocked enough times to resolve that it's 24 hours and not by the server day.

Comment: @Richard 8pm EDT is 0GMT, IIRC.  Sorry if my comment isn't clear, but it doesn't matter now.

Comment: -1 for a dinner that doesn't include waffles.

Comment: @Hans - why do you keep changing your picture, and thus the question?  The picture's difference is a dupe of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85121/reputation-summary-incorrect

Comment: @Nick - I'm trying to improve my question so it gets taken seriously.  It is the SE way.  My feature request hasn't fundamentally changed.  Sorry, I know how hard it is to produce accurate numbers.  But I'm only asking for the simple way to whack them back into shape.  It was suggested by Sam, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81885/new-users-page-is-missing-rep

Answer (score 15):

Do you *really* need your displayed reputation to *exactly* track your true reputation all the time? Whether you do 1 recalc an hour for 24 hours or 1 per day, the result at the end should be the same. What does it matter if it's temporarily off by a couple here or there, especially considering you're over **150k** now on SO?

Comment: It is setting the alarm clock that is so annoying.  Goes off at dinner time.

Comment: @Hans, then stop doing rep-recalcs at dinner time? =b

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned elsewhere, recalculating rep is a **server-intensive process that requires many CPU-cycles**, thus it is not a good idea to make rep recalcs more frequent, as that would *increase the server load*, which wouldn't be good.

Comment: The fraction of a second it takes for the rep page to refresh when you press the recalc button makes that sound a bit overblown.  This got optimized.

Comment: But isn't *showing* the report even more server-intensive, as that also needs to render the results? There's no limit in asking for that report though...

Comment: @Hans - The speed to display the page and the speed to do an actual recalc are not the same, as we go back and fix history affected by cap shifts and such when votes are deleted/removed...this doesn't happen for `/reputation` display, only the recalc.

Comment: @Richard - It can be (and is, always) more intensive to do a calculation than to show that (possibly-slighty-off) profile tab, it's *way* more intensive actually.

Comment: @Nick - I meant the /reputation page, not the reputation tab.

Comment: @Nick - thanks for the clarification. I thought the page was live and *accurate*, but thanks for clarifying

Comment: @Hans - I know, that's what I was speaking to :)

Comment: @Richard - it's accurate once a recalc is performed, but it's showing less-expensive denormalized data, rather than doing a full history view every time.  Particularly, in the case of rep-capping users it can skew more over time between recalcs.

Comment: @nick - `it's accurate once a recalc is performed` My point exactly. It's not "accurate", if we deem a recalc result as being "true and accurate". I thought it walked through the rules in a live manner, but it's only reporting from denormalized (aggregated) data.

Answer (score 4):

I support this 100%!!
I must know my exact rep at every second of the day. Not only that, *everyone else* must as well.

Whenever I get down-voted, I would like to be able to

1. delete the answer
2. `recalc` immediately so that my rep goes back up by +2 (not +1, +**2**!)

But more commonly, when I go past the daily rep cap

1. each down-vote takes off -2 *immediately*, but
2. each subsequent up-vote does *not* immediately restore the +2.

This is causing me quite a bit of stress and others to misinterpret my fabulousness <sub><sup>(aka reputation)</sup></sub>.

Please SO team, I need my rep to show 1789**8** not 1789**5** as it currently<sup>1</sup> does.  It is off by **3000**<sup>2</sup>!

<sub>This answer contains a bit of *sarcasm* in case you missed it</sub>

*<sub>1 As at UTC 20:24, 21 March 2011</sub>*
*<sub>2 milli-rep points</sub>*

Answer (score 3):

If there's really a problem here, shouldn't it be fixed where it's actually broken rather than making the workaround work a little better?

Comment: Can't agree more! Just one SQL query more whenever some `delete` action has been invoked doesn't seem to be very costly to me. Or they must be caching the values on such a crazy manner that it's fully detached from the DB's state and thus this ain't going to work.