# Reputation summary incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Today I was just checking my reputation summary on SO and it shows I have got 7 rep points today.

[image]

But when I go to my profile and see the reputation obtained for today, it shows only 5. Also realistically from yesterday my reputation has increased by 7, but I am unable to find from where I got the additional 2 reputation points. Is this a bug?

Just to add, I have not accepted any answers as such in last couple of days on SO.

[image]

Comment: What does [your detailed reputation list](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) say?

Comment: @Bobby - My complete reputation list also says I got only 5 reputation points

Comment: Somehow - this usecase is lost in my profile now. Only above screenshot is my proof for this discrepency. The day was 29-mar-2011. now it can be checked in Week rep count.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), the reputation change in your dropdown for *all* intervals is:

```
"how much did my reputation change?"
```

And in fact, your rep changed by 7, since someone reversed their downvote on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391198/easy-way-to-reverse-each-word-in-a-sentence/5391235#5391235), meaning your overall rep went up an additional 2 when that happened.

The view you're adding up, the reputation page, shows all votes that happened *that day*...but this vote wasn't cast on that day, just reversed/removed/deleted (which we don't show).

Comment: Just in case if I had more than 10k rep, would I be able to see this change like somebody reversed downvote or something like that? or only moderators can see this change?

Comment: @Sachin - This isn't currently show for anyone, even developers or moderators

Comment: Then how could you tell me the exact post on which I obtained this rep change? Just curious, please dont mind.

Comment: @Sachin - I had to manually query the database to find out what the change was in this case

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and effort. ;)

Comment: @SachinShanbhag - update, these changes will be shown in the reputation change list on all sites very soon: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes

Comment: OK, thanks. This was helpful for me. Was looking for the answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198888/inconsistent-reputation-display :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a repro.

[image]

I add up the numbers in the dropdown and they should be 177.

ps: I would do hand-drawn circles but I am still heartbroken at missing a chance to earn Mortarboard on two sites on the same day :-)

Comment: Thankyou upvoter for adding to the test case - the dropdown now says 186 for the week (ie still off by one) so the issue, whatever it is, persists through rep changes.

Comment: What browser are you using? Those headers with `177 V yesterday`, `10 V Mar 23`, etc should all be left-aligned!

Comment: @Chichiray IE 8 on Windows 7 with a wide screen 1366x768

Comment: Reproduced. I'd suggest to open an UI bug report.

Comment: Setting aside the issue of the alignment of the headers (I never knew they were supposed to be left aligned and they work fine for me) I see that both the dropdown and the rep page have changed this morning to include a downvote that I had forgotten, meaning the dropdown was **right** and the rep page was **wrong**. This morning, they agree.

Answer (score 4):

Someone withdrew a downvote, gaining you back the two points. The activiy dropdown reflects net change in reputation for that period, so the original vote wasn't cast today. The reputation tab on the user profile does not show withdrawn votes, thus the discreprancy.

Answer (score 3):

I reproduced this, as well.

[image]