# "Today"'s Rep Calculations Differ From Each Other

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation summary incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85121/reputation-summary-incorrect)

I've noticed a discrepancy between the reputation calculations for "today" depending on where I look.  For example, right now:

1. If I hover over my name at the top of the page, the fade-in box's table indicates a reputation change of 240 under the "Today" header.
2. If I go to my reputation tab on my profile, it indicates a reputation change of 255 in the "Today" group.

It appears that these two calculations disagree as to which day owns [an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530844/newbie-net-question-cant-find-control/5530930#5530930).

Comment: I'm not so sure this is a duplicate.  In the referenced question, the discrepancy is a result of a change to an existing vote.  This isn't a single vote being un-done, it's an answer being accepted.  (Maybe it was de-accepted and re-accepted at exactly the right time?)  Also, I'm able to reproduce this often.  It seems to happen on any day where I'm actively earning rep around the time that the day rolls over.