# Reputation Dropdown bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, reputation-page, activity-dropdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation summary incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85121/reputation-summary-incorrect)

I found today that the Reputation/Activity dropdown is off from the Reputation total in the profile page.  I added the numbers on the reputation page (178) and it's correct.  Here's the snapshot:

[image: Activity Dropdown bug]

**UPDATE:**  At the end of the day I had 215 in the activity dropdown, 216 on the reputation page of my profile, and 217 on the /reputation page.  The last vote had got me +8 on the profile reputation page, but +9 on the /reputation page.

The activity dropdown, after the first upvote of the new day, showed 10, but when I clicked on it to go to the profile reputation page, it didn't even show the upvote, still nothing listed for the new day.  The first vote after that was a downvote, and at that time I had 8 in both the dropdown, the profile reputation page, and the /reputation page, so it doesn't appear to be a holdover bug.

Comment: Maybe related, you got +9 yesterday for [one of your answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-someone-elses-code/101585#101585) and detailed view shows one upvote giving +9 at 22:49 and "empty" upvote (no reputation gain) at 23:24 - something here is weird..

Comment: @Shadow, the +9 was because I hit the rep cap and lost the 1 point.  So it might be related to this, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Nice, didn't think of rep cap! So maybe one of the "sources" mentioned by Chichiray still store that extra reputation point?

Comment: @Shadow, yeh, if I break the cap today, first thing I'll do is check the rep page and see if it shows a positive number.

Comment: @Nick, I think you missed the part about all three reputation summaries being different.  Please read the update.  Don't you think as programmers we could __design__ them all to match?

Comment: @Lance - Sure, of course, but it's a matter of *cost*, the queries aren't free...nor are they cheap at all, so we denormalize this.  Long term we have a plan to have all the values up to date, we just have more pressing work at the moment :)

Answer (score 5):

They are retrieved from different sources. Most likely an answer which you downvoted has been deleted and it is not been reflected in the user dropdown. When you trigger a recalc by the button at the bottom of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation, it'll be in sync.

Comment: They're both daily totals.  Shouldn't they not be dependent on doing a recalc, which should be a once-in-a-long-while thing?

Comment: I just checked.  The only answer I downvoted today has not been deleted.

Comment: That's because they are served from different sources. Likely some update (e.g. deletion of an answer which you downvoted) does not reflect one of the sources. I encounter this discrepancy almost daily on Stackoverflow.

Comment: By the way, the tooltip on your today's graph bar says 179: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13295/lance-roberts?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_graph

Comment: Hmmm, I get 178 there, but it's probably means something if you're getting something different.  p.s.  I just accepted an answer, so no need for anyone else to check.

Comment: Thinking once again about this, that I'm seeing 179 is likely because own downvotes are not visible in other's reputation data. Just wondering, did you today ever downvote a question which got deleted later? Perhaps the recalculation logic behind this has still to learn that question downvotes are free.

Comment: I downvoted one answer today, so I would have had 179, so your logic sounds right.  The answer has not been deleted, so it's not the larger issue.