# Recent reputation under profile triangle and profile is different

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation Dropdown bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101768/reputation-dropdown-bug)

If you look at

- the reputation in the report shown when you click on the profile triangle (does this report have a name?) and
- the "general" reputation report

… they are different.

Look at the question "how to deliberately trigger a StackOverflowException".

[image: Screenshot]

I received 2x upvote and 1x accept 2 days ago (10 Oct 2011), 1x upvote after rep limit yesterday (so a total of 3 upvotes and an accept) and in the report of the profile triangle it shows +35, like if I had just received 35 rep.

But these 35 rep I had received 2 days ago, and there are many other points I have received in between. It should have shown 0 rep.

Note that yesterday I was able to hit the rep cap of 200, so some upvotes I received didn't give me reputation. I don't know if this is connected to my "problem" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have just received 35 rep...I don't get what you mean.

The upvote yesterday was *after* you've hit the rep limit, which means you won't get reputation for that. the 35 rep are still from 2 days ago. If you hover over the +35 in the popup you'll get the timestamp.

I can't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: I hadn't ever noticed you could move the mouse over the rep points and see the length of time that single "group" of rep points was gained in. So the question should have been "what is the maximum length of time it will show the rep of?". Will it show only the rep gained in the last 24h or what? The last month?

Comment: And I HADN'T just received 35 rep. As I wrote, "these 35 rep I had received 2 days ago". If you consider "2 days ago" as "just"...