# Reputation summary bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, reputation-history

When I look at my daily reputation summary on [Server Fault](http://ServerFault.com/), it shows a net of +30 today for [Top-like tool for IP traffic](https://serverfault.com/questions/279164/top-like-tool-for-ip-traffic/279166#279166)

---

[image: SF daily rep summary]

---

However, if I click on the reputation tab, I see that I got an upvote on the question and then it was revoked; however, -10 revocation is not totaled correctly in the summary screenshot above.

---

[image: SF daily rep details]

---

AFAICT, this issue is not related to: [Reputation summary incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85121/reputation-summary-incorrect).

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That unupvote event is someone withdrawing their upvote from a *previous day* (an upvote and unupvote on the same post on the same day get collapsed and hidden). It is only shown under today because that's when the event occurred, but the physical reputation change occurs on whatever day the upvote originally occurred (that day would be recalculated to account for any possible lost reputation). So today, you have earned 30 reputation from that post.

Comment: How did you know the withdrawal is from a previous day? The graphic seems to show it happening at the same time

Comment: @MikePennington: *an upvote and unupvote on the same post on the same day get collapsed and hidden* - So seeing an unupvote at all implies that it's not from that day.