# Allow an individual to perform a manual rep recalculation on stackexchange.com every N days

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stackexchange.com, reputation-recalc

I try to recalculate my rep on all of the sites on a regular basis.  It's not too much of a hassle, but to go through each site I'm on, go to the `/reputation` page, recalc, go back, reload the page, etc., it becomes a bit of a chore.

I'm proposing a button on the `accounts` tab of `stackexchange.com` that would allow a manual rep recalculation over all of the sites that one is active on.  Realizing that such a convenience would come at the price of an increased server load, just as the `/reputation` page only allows a recalculation once every 24 hours, perhaps this new feature would be usable once every 3 days or 7 days.

Comment: Wouldn't this only be interesting on sites your actually active on, rather than **all** sites?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to question your motives: Who cares *so much* about reputation? Also, if you need to recalc often because f.e. questions/answers get deleted you ask/answer on...you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @IvoFlipse Yes, I agree, I tried to address that in the second para: `over all of the sites that one is active on`.

Comment: @Bobby My personal motives aren't at issue here, but one might care if there is a system-wide recalc after a long period of time and hundreds of points go missing.  It's just a means of keeping track.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rep recalculation is not something we intend to be done that often (that's why it's throttled, it's also one of the more expensive things for larger users).

However, we have plans so that this won't be needed anymore (so implementing this feature request is time better spent on *that*), stay tuned.

Comment: Nice future plan. Just for the curious, [an earlier comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84106/allow-more-frequent-rep-re-calculations/84108#comments-84108) from Nick: *The speed to display the page and the speed to do an actual recalc are not the same, as we go back and fix history affected by cap shifts and such when votes are deleted/removed...this doesn't happen for `/reputation` display, only the recalc.*