# Can we allow trusted users to recalculate reputation more often?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation-recalc

I would like to be able to recalculate reputation more often than once every 24 hours. While I'm sure you wouldn't want every user to do this as often as they like, I feel that the more trusted users (defined at whatever appropriate threshold) should be able to recalculate reputation on a more frequent basis. I typically find myself wishing to recalculate my reputation in the following circumstances:

- When I downvote an answer that is subsequently removed. I feel that my downvote has done its job, it has gotten the user to remove the unhelpful content.
- When I have removed by own [upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8736415/414076), either because it was duplicated or not as helpful as the score might indicate.

The *unearned* rep of the latter type actually bugs me like you wouldn't believe. But I have already burned through my daily recalc thanks to the former type.

---

Short of that, maybe at least give me the timestamp of my last recalc inside the "once per day" error message, so I'm not hitting that page more often than necessary.

Comment: Fear not, there are [big](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116235/159165) changes promised in this arena soon.

Comment: Yes, and waffles posted something similar enough. +1s all around. Case closed.

Comment: Why that recalc paranoia? I see no problem in waiting some hours to get a priviledge that you will probably never lose. If you want it just to the sake to see your rep number growing, even without earning nothing real, I should say that this was the cause of the dot-com bubble around 2000 and 2001, and you probably know what was the result. Instead of being paranoic about that, just be a good stackoverflow user and you will get your priviledges.

Comment: @Victor, you misunderstand, I'm less concerned about *the lost* rep or privileges, it's actually the *excess* rep that really grates at my last nerve. I want to give it back as quick as humanly possible. I guess it's just a personal hang-up no one else shares.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution proposed here does not treat the disease, it places onus on the end user and makes the overall experience more sucky.

Instead, there has been discussion in the past about doing partial recalc on answer/question deletion to the involved parties. I am more open to that, making our users visit a page every time something crazy like this happens seems ridiculous to me.

See also: 
[Trigger a rep recalc any time a post is deleted/undeleted or question migrated.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80898/trigger-a-rep-recalc-any-time-a-post-is-deleted-undeleted-or-question-migrated)

Comment: Is your second paragraph what Nick was talking about in the answer to my question, or is something else yet to be named in the works?

Comment: Nick is talking about a db restructure that will make it easier to do rep recalcs, this work has to be done before any other work like my mentioned proposal

Answer (score 7):

Are you that desperate to get your 1 reputation back after the post is deleted that you need to do it *right now*? I run mine like once a week just to see if anything has changed. It's really not *that* important that they need to implement something like this. Honestly, when looking at reputation, I only ever even look at the first number and how many digits.

Comment: Like I said, it's really the unearned upvote reputation that bugs me, really. I'm not concerned about the -1, I simply can't stand the unearned +10, +20, +30. Perhaps I'm alone.

Comment: @Anthony: It will get corrected eventually (with you, in ~24 hours), so I don't see much to worry about. Are you one of those people who goes back into the store when they give you extra change back?

Comment: Well actually, yes.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a ridiculous waste of resources. Even being able to recalculate rep every 24 hours is unnecessary.

If you have just recalculated, then you can keep manual track of your "actual" reputation by looking at your recent activity. Or, write an app to keep track of it. Or, post a series of questions on SO to get others to write it for you. This last approach is great because then you'll get lots of down votes and you can remove the questions later and recalculate your rep and watch it go up! But only every 24 hours. Alas, if only you could recalculate it every hour. Oh well, better do the pen and paper approach.