# Losing answer reputation from deleted questions discourages helping with basic problems

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-questions

A few weeks back, I posted [a fairly detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12425241/623041) in the hope that it would help the questioner overcome some pretty basic misunderstandings.

The question subsequently got closed for being "too localized", with which I disagreed and voted to reopen (because I can easily imagine other newcomers to PHP having similar misunderstandings).

The question never was reopened, and has now been deleted.  I think that's a shame, because it was a useful contribution to the community.  Certainly the wording could have been improved
 to make the problem clearer, but I don't think there was anything in the question that fundamentally merited its deletion.

Still, that's just my opinion.  I can accept that the community disagrees.

However, as if it wasn't bad enough that the time & effort spent posting a long, detailed and (hopefully) helpful answer has been rewarded with its removal from the site, I also understand that (per the discussion in [Deleted posts should not influence reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124754/161492)), I have also lost the (teensy) rep that I gained simply because the post didn't remain visible for 60 days!

What incentive is there for users to spend time helping newcomers with basic problems, if such questions are deemed so "localized" that their prompt closure & deletion removes every last scrap of reward those users stood to gain?  Was this really the intended outcome of this change to the reputation system?

Comment: That happened to me too, and I was a *bit* pissed off because I got a fair deal of rep to stabilize my privileges but then it was deleted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree that it should not have been deleted before at least trying to be improved.

I've undeleted it, but that doesn't mean people won't try to delete it again.

I agree that the wording could have been improved. Since you have over 22K reputation at the time of this writing, you could have even edited the question yourself!

Looking at the post, I'm sure it's a duplicate, so once I find the duplicate I'll close it as a duplicate of the other question. Since we prefer people not delete duplicates, it should at least stay undeleted for some time.

My somewhat rhetorical question to you is, *why didn't you take the time to improve it?* It certainly would have taken less time than posting a meta post about it.

**Be the change you wish to see in the world.**

For future reference, instead of meta, you can:

- Flag the post for moderator intervention, explaining that you think the question should not be deleted with your reasons, and be prepared to be asked to improve the question in return for its undeletion.

Comment: *[cue inspirational music, people holding their hands in the air, etc.]*